# Compiling errors in AndEngine GLES2

Tags: android, andengine

I'm trying to use AndAngine with GLES2, and when I'm trying to compile it I got a lot of errors in AndEngine's sources like

```
cannot find symbol variable BuildConfig
cannot find symbol variable HONEYCOMB
```

and

```
glDrawElements(int,int,int,java.nio.Buffer) in android.opengl.GLES20 cannot be applied to (int,int,int,int)
```

And, for example, BuildConfig.java even doesn't exist in `/src/org/andengine`, as import says!

Also, `HONEYCOMB`, `GINGERBREAD`, and `ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH` doesn't exist in Build.VERSION_CODES.

I've downloaded latest version of AndEngine from GitHub (branch GLES2), installed SDK's (API levels 7-16) and set `minSdkVersion` in AndroidManifest to "8". Does anyone know what I've missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, there's solution:

1) Module SDK must be 15 or higher

2) /gen folder must be in list of source folders

Answer (score 4):

For your AndEngine project - check the build target

right click on AndEngine - then left click on Properties - Android - make sure the Build Target is set to 15 or higher

Also be sure your development tools are up to date. If you are using Eclipse - Window | Android SDK Manager - make sure the top item "Android SDK Tools" is version 17+

Comment: Ok, almost all errors gone, but "cannot find symbol class BuildConfig" error still here.

Comment: BuildConfig.java is automatically generated - look in the AndEngine/gen folder

Comment: try updating your ADT - in Eclipse - Window | Android SDK Manager - according to the readme file you need to be at 17+ - I think the latest is version 20